# Order of execution for a recursive Fibonacci method

Tags: language-agnostic, recursion

ex:

```
public static int fibb (int n) {
    if(n==0||n==1)
        return 1;
    else{
        return fibb(n-1)+fibb(n-2);
      }
}
```

How will the line `fibb(n-1)+fibb(n-2)` be executed .. like will `fibb(n-1)` finish first the `fibb(n-2)` starts or how exactly, I'm fairly new to recursion and can't seem to wrap my head around how it works.

Help appreciated.

Comment: In which order `fibb(n-1)+fibb(n-2)` is executed is actually not related to recursion. You could have two functions `a` and `b` and ask the same about `a() + b()`.

Comment: yes that seems right ok for an n = 3 the first recursive call would be fibb(2) + fibb(1) my question is what happens at this point ?

Comment: check out [tree recursion](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/chapter1/node13.html) example

Comment: Well, `fibb(1)` will return `1` and `fib(2)` will execute `fibb(1)+fibb(0)`... where is the problem? So the result is `(fibb(1)+fibb(0)) + 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 fibb(3) returns fibb(2)                                +  fibb(1)
                 fibb(2) returns fibb(1) + fibb (0)

 so you get                         1     +     1       +       1   = 3



 fibb(4) returns fibb(3) + fibb(2), we know fibb(3) returns three from above,
 fibb(2) returns fibb(1) + fibb(0) also from above, 

 so fibb(4) returns 3 + 2 = 5
```

It's important to notice that with this implementation you must computer each previous Fibonacci number twice. Which means by the time you get to around ~20 (guess) it's going to get VERY slow.

Comment: Well, this kind of assumes that the language is both strict, and follows a defined left-to-right execution strategy.

Answer (score 2):

First, the recursive calls will be executed (the order in which being dependent on your programming language), then their results will be summed together.